# PowerBi IF Filter based on value in column from different table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 tables as below
Table1

```
 Value     Status
    A      Normal
    B      InProgress
    C      InProgress
```

Table2

```
Value   SLA
A      10:00
B      13:00 
C      Multiple Times a Day
```

I need to create a measure to return numbers based on status and Time values from column - SLA of Table2.
So, my conditions are:

```
1. If Status is "Normal" return 1
2. If Status is "InProgress", check corresponding 'SLA' value in Table2 and see if SLA is greater than current time or less than current time.
If its greater return 2, if its less return 3.
3. If SLA value is 'Multiple Times a Day' return 4.
```

How can I do this please? Thanks for help

Comment: And what is your question? What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Comment: I have tried creating a measure for same as below :
Status_Mod = 
if ( SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[STATUS])="Normal", 1,
if (SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[STATUS])="InProgress/ Due Later" && FILTER(Table1, RELATED(..))))

Stuck at above. Not getting option to pick column - SLA from Table2.
I have already created many to many relationship between both tables.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your two table has relationship.

When I simply had 1:1 from Table 1 to Table2 I could easily get desired result based on your condition.

Below Calculated field expression based on 1:1 Relationship. You might want to change your return value and small condition as I had Value from Table 2 as text.

```
  Return = IF('Table'[Status]="Normal";1;
IF('Table'[Status]="InProgress";IF(LOOKUPVALUE('Table (2)'[SLA];'Table (2)'[Value];'Table'[Value])>"10:00";2;2);IF(LOOKUPVALUE('Table (2)'[SLA];'Table (2)'[Value];'Table'[Value])="Multiple Times a Day";4;0))
)
```

Now when you change relationship from 1:1 to 1:M or M:M simple `LOOKUPVALUE` will not help as DAX will return many rows for 1 Primary Key.

Here you will need to use `CALCUALTE` or similar funciton depending on your actual data.
Now for simplyfication I created new Colum Return and gave value to it

[image]

```
Return = If('Table (3)'[SLA]="10:00";2;IF('Table (3)'[SLA]="Multiple Times a Day";4;3))
```

NOW Based on Return column I am using below function to return final result

```
Column = IF('Table'[Status]="Normal";1;CALCULATE ( 
Sum('Table (2)'[Return]);
FILTER(
    ALL('Table (2)');
    'Table (2)'[Value]='Table'[Value]
    )
    )
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for checking this and your reply. 
In IF I am not able to get that column value. I tried using 'SELECTEDVALUE' function but its also not returning correct text value ("Normal" or "InProgress").
That is why I am not able to run above mentioned measure.

Comment: You will not and that is because of relationship of your Table 1 and Table2.
What relationship you have, you might want to change to calculate function

Comment: I have created a M to M relationship. By using merge query, I have now created a third table but not able to filter that table now.

Comment: This is not working. Using below

Result_STATUS = IF(SELECTEDVALUE(new_table[STATUS])="Normal",1,
IF(SELECTEDVALUE(new_table[STATUS])="InProgress/ Due Later" && SELECTEDVALUE(new_table[Table2.SLA]) > NOW(),2,3))